# Как программно создать таблицу? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Пытаюсь так, но уже в четвертой строке ошибка

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{   
    var tr = new Array();
    var tr[i] = document.createElement('tr');
    tr[i].id = 'tr' + i;
    var td1 = new Array();
    var td2 = new Array();
    var td3 = new Array();
    var td1[i] = document.createElement('td');
    var td2[i] = document.createElement('td');
    var td3[i] = document.createElement('td');
    document.getElementById('stat').appendChild(tr[i]);
    td1[i].innerHTML='1';
    document.getElementById('tr' + i).appendChild(td1[i]);
    td2[i].innerHTML='2';
    document.getElementById('tr' + i).appendChild(td2[i]);
    td3[i].innerHTML='3';
    document.getElementById('tr' + i).appendChild(td3[i]);
}
```

**UPD** работающий вариант

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.id = 'tr' + 1;
    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
    document.getElementById('stat').appendChild(tr);
    td1.innerHTML = "1";
    document.getElementById('tr' + i).appendChild(td1);
    td2.innerHTML = "2";
    document.getElementById('tr' + i).appendChild(td2);
}
```

Comment: Какая ошибка-то?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: Конструкция `var tr[i]` не имеет смысла — вы или переменную создавайте, или значение в массив пихайте

Comment: если делаю без массива получается все в одну строку

Comment: Нужно забыть про пхп, и начать писать на js. ошибка очевидна _неверный синтаксис_. место тоже показали `var tr[i]` индекс у массивов начинается с 0, поэтому и цикл тоже неверен. чтобы добавить элемент в массив перед ним не надо писать `var`

Comment: @Grundy а причем пхп? я и близко его не знаю.

Comment: Потому что там в таком виде массивы заполняют

Comment: Попробуй написать комментарий, что по твоему должна делать каждая строчка твоего кода, тогда сразу будет понятно где ты ошибся

Comment: Ваш новый код даёт мне 10 строчек, и у каждой строчки свой ID. Что вам надо-то?

Comment: пример исправил, нужный эффект получен, если знаете более грамотный способ, напишите

Comment: я хотел получить 10 строк с ячейками 1,2,3

Comment: В чем на данный момент заключается вопрос?

Comment: все, я разобрался, в вопросе исправил пример, спасибо

Comment: мне тут сообщение вышло "требующим правки" , а причину я не пойму, может кто подсказать?

Comment: Надо было оставить вопрос как есть, а работающий вариант разместить как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стоит использовать `createElement` в цикле, это очень тяжёлая операция. Не стоит собирать строку в цикле добавлением текста в конец строки, по сравнению с добавлением элемента в массив, это тоже дорогая операция. Поэтому лучше собрать фрагменты текста в массив и выполнить join:

```
var tableArr=['<table>'];
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    tableArr.push('<tr><td>'+i+'</td></tr>');
}
tableArr.push('</table>');
document.getElementById('stat').innerHTML=tableArr.join('\n')
```

Comment: Хм, я всегда считал, что всё ровно наоборот, и заменял innerHTML на createElement везде где возможно. Есть где почитать про производительность createElement vs innerHTML?

Comment: Где-то на хабре была статья, про сравнение производительности при изменение DOM. Году  где-то в 2011.

Comment: Попытался найти ту статью, но к сожалению не смог. Нашёл только [утверждение](https://habrahabr.ru/post/316618/), что это так

Comment: Не экономьте на спичках! Производительность важна в тонких местах, а вот в таком коде который состоит из кучи строк которые потом засовываются в innerHTML вы потом хрен разберётесь. Не говоря уже о манипуляциях с DOM.

Comment: Стоит всё таки разделить innerHTML и формирование вставляемого в него текста. Куча фрагментов строк это реально зло. Поэтому я пользуюсь шаблонизаторами. А вот innerHTML это быстро, поэтому злом я это не назвал бы. Но нужно учитывать побочные эффекты: потеря фокуса и выделения текста в некоторых случаях. Поэтому следующий шаг - JSX.

Comment: @gimntut, ты неверно интерпретировал то, что написано по твоей ссылке. Там проблема не в том, что используется createElement, а то, что созданный элемент **вставлялся в дом** на каждой итерации, поэтому была рекомендация сначала все создать, неважно как: собрать строку или элементы в фрагмент и запихнуть в дом за один заход

Comment: Да нет, в моём ответе так и написано: 
_Не стоит использовать createElement **в цикле**_. Согласитесь трудно создать всю таблицу со всеми строками и ячейками одним createElement без цикла.

Comment: Я повторюсь, проблема не в _createElement **в цикле**._ А в том, что **на каждой итерации** этот элемент **добавляется _непосредственно в DOM_**. Собрать таблицу можно и без добавления в DOM, и потом просто добавить/заменить непосредственно одну таблицу, одним действием.

Comment: Жаль конечно, что вы вариант свой не запостили. А если все ячейки и строки в цикле будут создаваться и апендиться  в таблицу.. И  после этого вне циклов даблица будет добавляться  уже в DOM?Кпримеру в body или head? В этом случае производительность не пострадает..?Ведь в цикле у нас элементы добавляются  в таблицу которая ещё   не  вставлена  в body(head) а значит она ещё не в DOM?